# How to check if application is being run via SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm attempting to allow my application to use `System.exit(<int>)` so that when run via the command line on it's own outside of SBT it return a useful exit code.

When I exit whilst running through SBT's `run` command I get the following message:

```
Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-e"
```

I am aware of what this message is there for, and why it must be there.

I would like to avoid exiting if my code is being run via SBT. Is it possible to detect whether or not code is being run via SBT? If so, how?

Comment: Your `main` can inspect the stack for sbt, `Thread.currentThread.getStack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using SBT's `fork` setting. In your build.sbt, add:

```
fork := true
```

For further refinement on which tasks to fork, consult SBT's documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html

Comment: What are the side effects of doing this? Does it affect debugging?